# Unable to insert data through EntityRepository.create or EntityRepository.persist #MikroOrm #NestJS

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm, nestjs-testing

:)

I am trying to test my Entity operations using the code in the file.
I am creating a userRepository object as follows:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t61Sz.png)

When I console.log find{} from the repository, it fetches the previously stored records:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP1yx.png)
I create a dummy object using faker and it works fine but as soon as I try to create it in DB or persist it, it does not seem to work:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtqLl.png)

I also tried orm.em.persist. Let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future readers, this has been asked & asnwered on the GH.

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/discussions/1571